# php isJson method php version error

Tags: php

```
function isJson($string) {
 json_decode($string);
 return (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE);
}
```

Actually, `json_last_error` is working on PHP 5.3 and upper versions but now i will use PHP 5.2 Server so this method will not work. Please tell me any alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_decode will return NULL if json string cannot be decoded so might check with this:

```
function isJson($string) {
 return json_decode($string) != null;
}
```

Comment: `function isJson($string){ 
    return json_decode($string) != null;
}`
Like this ?

Comment: This method will return true or 1  ?

Comment: this will return true or false. if you echo it, 1 or empty string

Comment: I'm using multiple search and working with json this function will check if string json using multiple search if not json using single json i have to check string json or not i used this function but function return nothing used echo function again return nothing i have to check return value

Comment: what is the string you are testing?